# Create a List of pairs in .net

Tags: .net

I need to create a `List<>` of pairs of my classes. such as:
`List<Class1, Class2>`

How would you do it?
I can not use the "Pair" datatype because it's in system.web.UI.

Would you create a list of arrays?
Create a struct of both classes and add them to a list?

Is there another way I don't know of and I'm just a noob?

Note:
I don't want the list to auto-sort in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know some people get uncomfortable about this - see a discussion [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UsingTheASPNETCacheOutsideOfASPNET.aspx) - but there's nothing to stop you referencing System.Web in a non-web project, and then you can use `System.Web.UI.Pair` quite happily.

Comment: I think this is the best approach, why re-invent the wheel

Comment: My teammates will hate me.. but I'll go with that (I'm extremely embarrassed though and really hate microsoft for making "Pair" available only on the web.

Comment: Pair's not something I've come across before but it does look so generic that it should be in the System namespace, not System.Web.UI.

Comment: Poor solution really - this is overkill in the situation.  Why introduce a dependency for such a simple class construct? "Don't re-invent the wheel" is fair enough, but Pair is such a simple construct it's not worth adding dependencies to System.Web for.

Answer (score 9):

I just use this:

```
var list = List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>;
```

or any other data type of course.  It means you are accessing it like `list(0).Key` and `list(0).Value` but this doesn't bother me unless I am exposing the list externally.

Comment: Will it autosort my list? (I don't want to)

Comment: No - a List is essentially a resizable array - every element will be a KeyValuePair. They will be maintianed in the order you add the elements.

Answer (score 8):

Simply create your own pair class:

```
class Pair<TFirst, TSecond> {

  public TFirst First { get; set; }

  public TSecond Second { get; set; }

}
```

Initialize it like this:

```
Pair<String, String> pair = new Pair<String, String> {
  First = "first",
  Second = "second"
};
```

The next release of .NET (4.0) has tuples which is a more general solution to the problem.

Comment: This is a much better solution than using KeyValuePair as mentioned elsewhere, as "KeyValuePair" implies there is a Key / Value relationship, which there probably isn't (in the OP's question).

Answer (score 2):

As Hans Kesting points out, you could create your own Pair class, but often such a construct tends to cover up the fact that the relationship between the two types you are trying to pair actually represent a stronger concept in your API.

So instead of ending up with a generic Pair (or Tuple) your code may be more readable if you explicitly type the pair as a strong concept with good naming.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own Pair class ...

Comment: Or struct. A value type might be more appropriate than a reference type.

Answer (score 1):

It's designed to be used in Dictionaries, but you could use a [KeyValuePair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a generic Dictiontary instead of a generic list?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with using a dictionary unles you can have mulitple values that are the same as dictionaries require unique *Key* values.

If you really needed pairs, you could make a class to do it and use it like this:

```
List<Pair<string, int>> pairs = new List<Pair<string, int>>();
pairs.Add(new Pair<string, int>("entry1", 1));
pairs.Add(new Pair<string, int>("entry2", 2));
```

Class

```
public class Pair<T, T2>
{
    T Value1;
    T2 Value2;
     public Pair(T value1, T2 value2)
     {
         Value1 = value1;
         Value2 = value2;
     }
}
```

I used generics because you didn't specify what type (this will work with any 2 Types).  you could simplify it even more if you hard-coded the types.

Comment: This way will work, but I agree with PhilPursglove - just reference System.Web.UI.Pair

Answer (score 1):

Surely anonymous types are suited perfectly for this:

```
var Pair = new { Part1 = "A", Part2 = 6 };
var PairList = (new[] { Pair }).ToList();
PairList.Add(new { Part1  = "B", Part2  = 9 });

...

List[0].Part1 = "C";
```

Basically this is making a new "var object" containing a string and an int. Adding it to an array and invoking the ToList() extension method provided by System.Linq on the array to return an object which is effectively List<"typeof(Pair)"> object.

(EDIT)

Or neater still:

```
var PairList2 = (new[] { new { Part1 = "A", Part2 = 6 } }).ToList();
```

(ideas pinched from: http://kirillosenkov.blogspot.com/2008/01/how-to-create-generic-list-of-anonymous.html)

Comment: Don't think anonymous types are supported in framework 2, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a Dictionary<>

Comment: Except a `Dictionary<>` doesn't maintain item order like a `List<>` does.

Comment: Svish. No. SortedDictionary sorts by key, not by insertion order

Answer (score 0):

I would go with either KeyValuePair (as used by Dictionary) or create my own struct that acts as a typed container, emphasising the relation between the types.

By the time I've typed this several people have posted much the same - but I'll post this anyway for reassurance :-)

Answer (score 0):

One answer to everybody (It's the same answer and I don't want to add comments for everyone...):

I feel like using Key-Value combinations (or dictionary) is not natural because it's not representing a key and a value.

I'm trying to avoid creating my own class to represent the pair.

Maybe I'll import the System.Web.UI... feels crappy about it though